# Why does this not output my text when holding the required key?

Tags: c#

I have been working with GetAsyncKeyState in C# and I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, I want this to output to console everytime I am pressing space but it doesn't. I have spent far too long on this little problem and need your help!

```
    namespace key_input
{
    class Program
    {

        #region DLLS
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);
        #endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            if (true)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
                while (GetAsyncKeyState(32) > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are pressing the spacebar!");
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [GetAsyncKeyState Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293(v=vs.85).aspx) `Remarks: The GetAsyncKeyState function works with mouse buttons.`

Comment: When your code starts, it hits the `ReadLine` method and waits for you to press Enter.  Once you press Enter, the code continues into the `while` loop and checks the state of the key.  If it is not pressed, the program will run to the end of the `Main` method and immediately exit.  If the spacebar is not pressed when it checks, it will drop out of the `while` loop.

Comment: @blaze_125 - The method doesn't _only_ work with mouse buttons.  That remark in the docs means it works with mouse buttons _also_.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I have taken out ReadLine and changed it to a while loop but it still is not working.

`while (true)
            {
                
                while (GetAsyncKeyState(32) > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You are pressing spacebar!");
                    
                }
                
            }`

Comment: @ChrisDunaway, thank you! I stand corrected and validated what you just said. Now I wonder if I should remove my first comment?

Comment: @enyap - If you are not pressing the spacebar when it first hits the `while` loop, the loop will just exit immediately.

Answer (score 1):

This does not use Interop services like your snippet does but, the end results seems to be what you are after.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pressed it");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually was familiar with this to begin with, thank you for sharing it though! But using this seems to have a delay, and I am looking for a resolution that doesn't have an input delay. For example if you hold space with this method it writes the input to console, then after a delay continues to display the input.

Comment: took me a few attempts to figure out what you just said... but yeah... I see the "delay" you are talking about. If you do "single presses" then every spacebar press instantly writes to Console. Though, if you hold the spacebar, the first instance instantly gets written to console, but instances 2+ start appearing after a "delay". Is that it?

Comment: Yes, GetAsyncKeyState does not have a delay like that. The program I am trying to make would not be as good as it could be if it has a delay like that so I need it to register without the delay.